# I am not able to search my users by email using JPA spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Controller

```
package com.bird.bird.Controllers;

import com.bird.bird.Entity.Manager;
import com.bird.bird.Repository.ManagerRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/manager")
public class ManagerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ManagerRepository managerRepository;


    @GetMapping("/teste")
    public Object teste() {
        return "teste";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Manager save(@RequestBody Manager manager){
        return managerRepository.save(manager);
    };
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Manager> findAll(){
        return managerRepository.findAll();
    };

    @GetMapping("/findID/{id}")
    public Manager findById( @PathVariable int id){
        return managerRepository.findById(id);
    };

    @GetMapping("/findCPF/{CPF}")
    public Manager findByCPF( @PathVariable String CPF){
        return managerRepository.findByCPF(CPF);
    };
}
```

Repository

```
package com.bird.bird.Repository;

import java.util.List;

import com.bird.bird.Entity.Manager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ManagerRepository extends JpaRepository<Manager, Integer> {

    Manager findById(int id);
    Manager findByEmail(String email);
    Manager findByCPF(String CPF);
    //Manager findByPhone(String phone);

}
```

Entity

```
package com.bird.bird.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "manager")
public class Manager implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int IdManager;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Name;
    @Column(name = "birth", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String Birth;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String Email;
    @Column(name = "CPF", length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String CPF;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Password;
    @Column(name = "phone", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Phone;
    @Column(name = "address", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Address;
    @Column(name = "city", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String City;
    @Column(name = "state", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String State;
    @Column(name = "zipcode", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String ZipCode;
    @Column(name = "country", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Country;

    public Manager() {
    }
    public Manager(String name, String birth, String email, String CPF, String password, String phone, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode, String country) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Birth = birth;
        this.Email = email;
        this.CPF = CPF;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Phone = phone;
        this.Address = address;
        this.City = city;
        this.State = state;
        this.ZipCode = zipCode;
        this.Country = country;
    }

    public int getIdManager() {
        return IdManager;
    }

    public void setIdManager(int idManager) {
        IdManager = idManager;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return Birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(String birth) {
        Birth = birth;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getCPF() {
        return CPF;
    }

    public void setCPF(String CPF) {
        this.CPF = CPF;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return ZipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        ZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }
}
```

Error:
eption: Error creating bean with name 'managerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'managerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managerRepository' defined in com.bird.bird.Repository.ManagerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed

Resume:
I would like to do an email search to test, then another login to compare email and password

Comment: can u post ur configuration class and controller class.

Comment: I'm still learning, it doesn't have a configuration class

Comment: I also put my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your manager class, you have defined all the fields starting with Capital letter ( which is wrong by convention) , therefore you need to update them with small letters only then we will be able to use jpa interface data derived queries ( findByFieldName)
So update the Email field in Manager class to this :

```
private String email ;    
// standard  getters and setters
```

In addition to this,

```
 @GetMapping("/findByEmail/{email}")
public Manager findByEmail(@PathVariable String email){
    return managerRepository.findByEmail(email);
};
```

you need to update this to get mapping. When retrieving objects from database, we use @GetMapping and not Post . also ,we pass variables in the url and not in the request body.

Comment: I'm switching to the form you mentioned

Comment: is it possible to share your project on github?

Comment: Yes one moment.

Comment: Your solution removed the error, but it is not bringing the answers to the queries

Comment: github: https://github.com/NatSilva/Bird-api

Comment: @AmandaNunes you don't have a request mapping for the email field.just like you've added for different fields, add a get mapping for email field too

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: I noticed something, when I send via get via the url and I get it, but via post it doesn't return anything

Comment: ```@PostMapping("/findByEmail")
    public Manager findByEmail(@RequestBody String email){
        return managerRepository.findByEmail(email);
    };```

Comment: does the update5d answerr work?

Comment: but so I'm in doubt, if I want to request a login, do I also need to send email and password by url? Wouldn't that be reckless for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Add **@Repositroy** annotation to ManagerRepository
and change your class, like

```
public class Manager {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idManager;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "birth", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String birth;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "CPF", length = 30, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String cpf;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "phone", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "address", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "city", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "state", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "zipcode", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String zipCode;
    @Column(name = "country", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String country;

    public ManagerDao(int idManager, String name, String birth, String email, String cpf, String password, String phone, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode, String country) {
        this.idManager = idManager;
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.email = email;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getIdManager() {
        return idManager;
    }

    public void setIdManager(int idManager) {
        this.idManager = idManager;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(String birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Then delete ";" your methods in controller after "}"  is not need.

[Gurkirat Singh Guliani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15318227/gurkirat-singh-guliani)  answered right

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: I don't have a configuration class, I don't know what this is, I'm still learning

Comment: The error is not in the control, but when I save with findByEmail, it already has an error and doesn't let me use

Comment: I can't start with this findByEmail in the repository

Comment: what goes inside the configuration class?

Comment: in your case, nothing

Comment: I added the class, but the error still persists.

Comment: Adding the annotation to a Spring Data JPA repository is useless, it only adds an annotation that does nothing. So it is actually harder to read, with more code that actyally doesn't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hello, this is not entirely true. Imagine situation, when need find all repositories.  You can find their by applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Repository.class);